# AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap returns null data

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have an error with missing data that is converted by TupleConverter using `@Query` annotation for SQL statement. I don't know why, but some columns are null.

```
@Repository
public interface ExpenseRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long> {

    @Query(value = """
            SELECT E.name, E.amount, C.name, E.description, T.name
            FROM expense E
            INNER JOIN category C ON C.id = E.category_id
            INNER JOIN timestamp T ON T.id = E.timestamp_id
            """, nativeQuery = true)
    List<ExpenseDTO> getAll();

}
```

```
public interface ExpenseDTO {
    String getName();
    double getAmount();
    String getCategory();
    String getDescription();
    String getTimestamp();
}
```

Results for the code below

```
List<ExpenseDTO> allExpenses = expenseService.getAllExpenses();
        allExpenses.forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println(MessageFormat
                    .format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", 
                            x.getName(), x.getAmount(), x.getCategory(), x.getTimestamp(), x.getDescription()
                    ));
        });
```

[image: Output]

[image: MySql result]

Another strange thing is that `expense.name` is taken from `timestamp.name` column, but I mentioned the table before selecting column inside SQL statement.

Entities are generated with Spring JPA and for constraints between tables I used `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn(tableName_id)` annotations inside `Expense` entity. Any help will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were 3 columns in the SQL result with same name `e.name`, `t.name`, `c.name`, and somehow instead of throwing any exception or repeating data inside each column, it returned null. Alias inside @Query resolved this issue.

Solution

```
@Query(value = """
        SELECT E.name, E.amount, C.name as 'Category', E.description, T.name as 'Timestamp'
        FROM expense E
        INNER JOIN category C ON C.id = E.category_id
        INNER JOIN timestamp T ON T.id = E.timestamp_id
        """, nativeQuery = true)
List<ExpenseDTO> getAll();
```